# socket.io connecting but not firing events on ios10

Tags: jquery, node.js, websocket, socket.io, ios10

I'm using jquery/socket.io/nodejs. Until iOS 10 (iPad - not tested on iPhone), this used to work and get a good connection to the server. This is abstracted from a larger project, to duplicate the issue. The nodejs server gets the connection in this example, as seen in it's log file.

I don't have a connection to the browser console, since it's an iPad. Using Safari, though Chrome does not work also. I tried putting a "try/catch" around this (not shown here) and the "catch" never fires.

Socket.io uses websockets, which is not IPv6 compatible, so Apple may have an issue with that, but I have not found any definitive answers referencing that.

Have read somewhere that Apple may cripple javascript that uses "eval", but again could not find anything more definitive.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>iOS10 Socket.io Test</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ws://dev.website.com:3002 http://dev.website.com ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; media-src * ;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ;connect-src 'self' *" />

    <script src="lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/socket.io-1.4.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div id='debug' style="margin:12px;border:1px solid red;"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var tt = this;
            tt.debugPrint = function(s) {
                console.log(s);
                $("#debug").append(s + "<br>\n");
            }
            tt.io = io; // grab global "io"
            var href = 'http://dev.website.com:3002';
            tt.socket = tt.io.connect(href);

            if (tt.socket) 
                tt.debugPrint("socket created");

            tt.socket.on('connected', function(data) {
                tt.debugPrint("connected");
            });

            tt.socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
                tt.debugPrint("disconnected");
            });

            tt.socket.on('reconnecting', function(data) {
                tt.debugPrint("reconnecting");
                console.error(data);
            });

            tt.socket.on('reconnect', function(data) {
                tt.debugPrint("reconnect");
                console.error(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you enable _Web Inspector_ in mobile Safari (_Settings > Safari > Advanced_), you can then use desktop Safari to access the console of mobile Safari. That said: my `socket.io` projects work just fine in iOS 10, both from iPad and iPhone. I'm not using IPv6 either.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks! Using the Web Inspector, I did find "socket.io-1.4.5.js:1:28010 SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure." I'm using HTTP since this is a development system and does not have HTTPS. I hosted this HTML on another site that has HTTPS, and the connection is successful, though it complains about insecure content from the WS connection, which it should. Guess that answer is that iOS 10 requires HTTPS/WSS for socket.io

Comment: Hmm yeah that might be right, I _am_ using HTTPS myself. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7772), it may provide some workarounds.

Comment: @robertklep From what I have read online, in Jan 2017 Apple's "App Transport Security" requirements will deny any Apps that use IP literals in their protocols (some IPv6 issue), and Websockets is one of those "bad" protocols. Any links to information on how to address this issue regarding socket.io? (Sorry, Google/StackOverflow/GitHub search failed me on this one).

Comment: I thought ATS only applied to apps submitted to the App Store? Or is the code in your question part of such an app? I can't imagine that Safari would block WS/WSS because of ATS rules (although you never know with Apple).

Comment: @robertklep Sorry, I should have been more clear. Our project is a one-page website, that will also be ported to Apple/Android APPs using PhoneGap. Socket.io supports all platforms, which is why we love it. If Apple really applies ATS, then all browser APPS must NOT support WS/WSS since they would violate ATS. Would Apple do this? Who knows. We are early enough in development to drop socket.io and do long-polling, but I would rather not.

Comment: Well, you can always downgrade `socket.io` to use [a polling transport](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#transports) if absolutely necessary, but obviously, you probably want to get it working over websockets. Why not use WSS though? You're already using HTTPS.